# Why a for loop stops at 2nd iteration reading an UTF coming from the client?

Tags: java, loops, sockets, object, server

im trying the following: im doing a Server-Client message exchange. Im asking to the client the number of tasks he wants to perform and asking for a description and status of the task in the first for loop, and later create a object from the class i've created, and put it inside the ArrayList. When it comes the second iteration the console hangs and never asks for the third or any number of iteration that is further from the 2nd one. Then i guess that the same problem is happening in the status... That is the code i've writed for the excercise, sorry if is for someone a silly question, im new and im trying to learn. Thank you very much

`Server.java`

```
package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    private final int Port = 9876;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
        ArrayList<Tarea> tarea = new ArrayList<Tarea>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Server() throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port);
        socket = new Socket();
    }

    public void iniciarServidor() throws IOException {
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Esperando al cliente");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("El cliente se ha conectado");
            DataOutputStream input = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream output = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            input.writeUTF("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
            String nombre = output.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Nombre cliente: " + nombre);

            String descripcion = "";
                        boolean estado;
                        
            Tarea t = new Tarea();
                input.writeUTF("Muy buenas " + nombre
                        + " especifique numero de tareas:");
                                int numeroTareas = output.readInt();
                                
                                for(int i = 0;i<numeroTareas;i++){                                                        
                                   
                                    input.writeUTF("Especifique descripcion para la tarea "+i+" :");
                                    descripcion = output.readUTF();
                                    input.writeUTF("Especifique el estado 'true o false' para la tarea "+i+" :");
                                    estado = output.readBoolean();
                                    
                                    t = new Tarea(descripcion,estado);  
                                    tarea.add(t);
                                    
                                }
                                
                                sc.nextLine();
                                
                        
                                input.writeUTF("El servidor va a enviar todas las tareas");
                                
                                for(int i = 0;i<tarea.size();i++){
                                    input.writeUTF("Numero tarea: "+i);
                                    input.writeUTF("Descripcion: "+tarea.get(i).getDescripcion());
                                    input.writeUTF("Estado: "+tarea.get(i).isEstado());
                                }
                                            
        

            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Cliente desconectado");
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
    }
    
}
```

`Client.java`

```
package client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import server.Tarea;


public class Client {

    private final String Host = "localhost";
    private final int Port = 9876;
    private final Socket socket;
    ArrayList<Tarea> tarea = new ArrayList<Tarea>();


    public Client() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(Host, Port);
    }

    public void iniciarCliente() throws IOException {
        
        String descripcion;
        boolean estado;
        

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Servidor solicita nombre usuario
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        output.writeUTF(sc.nextLine());
        //Numero de tareas a realizar
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        output.writeInt(sc.nextInt());
        sc.nextLine();
        //Servidor solicita descripcion tarea
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        descripcion = sc.next();
        output.writeUTF(descripcion);
        //Servidor solicita estado de tarea
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        estado = sc.nextBoolean();
        output.writeBoolean(estado);
        //Servidor confirma que va a enviar las tareas
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        //Servidor envia todas las tareas;
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());
        


        socket.close();
        input.close();
        output.close();
        System.out.println("Fin, Desconectado del servidor");
        sc.close();

    }


}
```

`Tarea.java`

```
package server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Lluis
 */
public class Tarea {
    
    private String descripcion;
    private boolean estado;
    
    
    public Tarea(){
        
    }
    
    public Tarea(String descripcion, boolean estado){
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    
    public String mandarDesc(ArrayList<Tarea> tarea) {
        
        for(int i=0; i<tarea.size(); i++) {
            setDescripcion(tarea.get(i).getDescripcion());
        }
        
        return getDescripcion();
    }
    
    public boolean mandarEstado(ArrayList<Tarea> tarea) {
        
        for(int i=0; i<tarea.size(); i++) {
            setEstado(tarea.get(i).isEstado());
        }
        
        return isEstado();
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return getDescripcion()+ " Estado: /n " + isEstado();
    }

    /**
     * @return the descripcion
     */
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    /**
     * @param descripcion the descripcion to set
     */
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    /**
     * @return the estado
     */
    public boolean isEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    /**
     * @param estado the estado to set
     */
    public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What jumps to my attention:

`Server.java`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
...
sc.nextLine();
```

Is it possible that your server is waiting for a keypress on stdin rather than on the network socket?